# Swift 3: Filter a range

Tags: swift, filter, functional-programming

In Swift 2 it was possible to filter a range like this:

```
let range: Range<Int> = 1..<100
let mult4 = range
    .filter{n in n % 4 == 0}
```

In Swift3 the range seems to have lost its filter method. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you hadn't of added the `Range<Int>` explicit type annotation, your code would still compile ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use a *countable range*:

```
let range: CountableRange<Int> = 1..<100
// Or simply: let range = 1..<100

let mult4 = range.filter { n in n % 4 == 0 }
```

A `(Closed)Range` describes an "interval" and can not be enumerated,
whereas a `Countable(Closed)Range` is a collection of consecutive values.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `stride`:

```
let mult4 = Array(stride(from: 0, to: 100, by: 4))
```

Comment: This is a better solution. Not a direct answer of course, but for this particular example it's faster and uses less ram

Comment: @Alexander: It is certainly a good solution, but I doubt that there is any difference in terms of memory consumption.

Comment: @MartinR Whoops, I thought for a second that OP's code was `Array(range).filter...`

Answer (score 1):

```
let range: Range<Int> = 1..<100
let mult4 = [Int](range.lowerBound..<range.upperBound).filter{n in n % 4 == 0}
```